# how to change the shortcut icon in google app engine

Tags: html, google-app-engine

The current shortcut icon that appears on top of my page at www.bad-coder.appspot.com is the default aeroplane engine favicon ico. while I did change the favicon ico to my custom one but it is not showing up in chrome while it does show up in firefox. I have already disabled cache and and deleted the previous cache also in chrome but still the shortcut icon on the tab doesn't change .

How do i cahnge it?

I have already written this in the header

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Facebook Connect Demo</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.bad-coder.appspot.com/favicon.ico">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option you have is to use the app.yaml configuration file. Add this to the `app.yaml` file (under your gae dir):

```
- url: /favicon.ico
static_files: static/images/favicon.ico
upload: static/images/favicon.ico
```

And place you `favicon.ico` or whatever, in the specified path : `static/images/favicon.ico` in this case.

If you've already done this, and it still persists, then I guess this might warrant a different solution.

Comment: I don't have a app.yaml file ...how do i create one which directory should I put it in ? ...I am deploying a simple java application using html and javascript only

Comment: Assuming your project is contained in the folder `folder`, then just create a file `folder/app.yaml`. Doesn't matter whether this is a plain html, python or java app.

Comment: didn't need the yaml file just created a folder called static with the favicon ico inside ,under war folder and pointed the link to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to link your favicon in the header as long as the directory it's in is configured as a static directory in `app.yaml`, e.g.:

```
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
```

If you put the image in a directory named `/static`,

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.bad-coder.appspot.com/static/favicon.ico">
```

should work. The original link won't, because your root directory isn't configured to serve static files. Here's the [Java documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/appconfig_yaml) on `app.yaml`. It's a pretty simple file that lives in the root directory of your app and handles some common settings.

Comment: where do i have to put the app.yaml file and the static directory..should it be inside the war directory???

Comment: also there seems to be an issue with portability with app.yaml to other java based servers its written in the docs itself that you gave me..is there any web.xml based solution to this

Comment: wheww it worked..I just put it inside a static directory and pointed the link to that directory :)   ...and also app.yaml is not the exact solution as it seems to cause portability issues and this technique works without writing yaml file

Comment: I'm not familiar with using the Java runtime on GAE. You might want to add a "java" tag to your question for more specific answers on stuff like web.xml.